# Introducir datos de listas anidadas en python

Tags: python, array-bidimensional

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código en Python

```
ficha=[]
alumnos=[]
nombre=input("Dame un nombre: ")
while nombre!="":
    nota=input("Dame la nota:")
    ficha.append(nombre)
    ficha.append(nota)
    alumnos.append(ficha)
    ficha.clear()
    nombre=input("Dame un nombre: ")
print(alumnos)
```

La salida siempre me sale como una lista vacía. Y si elimino la línea que dice ficha.clear() la lista aparece llena, pero con los últimos valores introducidos en nombre y nota repetidos una y otra vez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema en tu código es que estás agregando la misma lista `ficha` a la lista `alumnos` en cada iteración del bucle `while`. Al hacerlo de esta manera, estás agregando una referencia a la misma lista `ficha` cada vez que se ejecuta el ciclo, en lugar de agregar una copia de los valores actuales.

Para solucionarlo, puedes crear una nueva lista `ficha` en cada iteración del bucle `while`, de la siguiente manera:

```
alumnos=[]
nombre=input("Dame un nombre: ")
while nombre!="":
    ficha=[]
    nota=input("Dame la nota:")
    ficha.append(nombre)
    ficha.append(nota)
    alumnos.append(ficha)
    nombre=input("Dame un nombre: ")
print(alumnos)
```

En este código, se crea una nueva lista `ficha` en cada iteración del bucle `while`, lo que garantiza que los valores se agreguen correctamente a la lista `alumnos`.

Comment: La verdad es que no entiendo por qué el programa no puede funcionar de la forma que lo he escrito yo, pero el caso es que no funciona. Y con el cambio que propones sí funciona. Gracias por la respuesta y por la rapidez.